# configure jms_i18n_routing for InvalidConfigurationException

Tags: symfony, routes, jms

I want to use the JMSi18nRoutingBundle. So i already have installed it in my project. Now when i try to run the server the commandline says:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]

The child node "default_locale" at path "jms_i18n_routing" must be configured.
```

But the path in this file is dynamic and will be only changed through the `setPath()` method. So where and how i have to configure it?

Comment: i found out that the configuration for the bundle have to be set in the `config.yml` so i edit it and now i have this message: 

`[RuntimeException]
    The JMSI18nRoutingBundle requires Symfony2's translator to be enabled. Plea
se make sure to un-comment the respective section in the framework config.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok solved it!

the configuration to the JMSi18nRoutingBundle:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [en, de]
    strategy: prefix
```

need to be written in the `config.yml`. Additionally to this, the Translator in the Config has to be enabled. That´s all.